# High-Res profiling using DevTools

Tags: web, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

Im trying to work with the DevTools performance profiler to analyse the performance of a web application. But the sample rate is not high enough for my needs. It is sampling the stacks around every ~1ms.

I came accross [Chrome DevTolls November'13 Digest](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=9633a746551b3934JmltdHM9MTcwMTU2MTYwMCZpZ3VpZD0zODNiYzgzYS1iZTU3LTZlZGQtMWNkZS1kYmY0YmZjNzZmOGMmaW5zaWQ9NTQyNA&ptn=3&ver=2&hsh=3&fclid=383bc83a-be57-6edd-1cde-dbf4bfc76f8c&psq=how%20to%20enable%20high%20resolution%20profiling%20devtools&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXIuY2hyb21lLmNvbS9ibG9nL2RldnRvb2xzLTIwMTMtMTEvIzp-OnRleHQ9VG8lMjBlbmFibGUlMjBIaWdoJTIwUmVzb2x1dGlvbiUyMFByb2ZpbGluZyUyMCUyOGN1cnJlbnRseSUyMENhbmFyeSUyMG9ubHklMjklM0EsdW5kZXIlMjBQcm9maWxlciUyQyUyMHR1cm4lMjBvbiUyMEhpZ2glMjByZXNvbHV0aW9uJTIwQ1BVJTIwcHJvZmlsaW5nLg&ntb=1) that says to enable High resolution CPU profiling. but I couldn't find it in the DevTools settings

I looked for it in Chrome Canary and Edge Canary, with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a 10 year old article. Devtools uses highres profiling by default [since 2020](https://crbug.com/1082220). If that's not enough you can try the old JS profiler, it's enabled in experiments in devtools preferences.